# Moment JS format() not displaying correct time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

This result is wrong:

```
console.log(moment("2020-08-07 09:10:48", "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
        .format("ddd, DD.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
```

-> Fri, 07.08.2020 00:00:00

---

These return the correct values

```
console.log(moment("2020-08-07 09:10:48").hour())
```

-> 9

```
console.log(moment("2020-08-07 09:10:48").format())
```

-> 2020-08-07T09:10:48+02:00

Apparently the date was correctly parsed but format does not work as expected?

Comment: `moment("2020-08-07 09:10:48", "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")` and `moment("2020-08-07 09:10:48")` do different things...You're not comparing apples with apples here

Comment: What exactly are you expecting the "correct time" to be? This question is very unclear

Comment: Yeah wanted to edit but haven't found the button. The first result is wrong. The latter prove the parse to have worked.

Comment: The OP question is a little bit hided: he doesn't know how to correct format a date in moment

Comment: Like I said your not comparing apples with apples here. Also `moment("2020-08-07 09:10:48")` is going to parse that string using ISO date time, is that what you want?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your are passing `yyyy` which is wrong. Expected `YYYY`

Try this.

```js
console.log(moment("2020-08-07 09:10:48", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").format("ddd, DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss"))

console.log(moment("2020-08-07 09:10:48").hour())

console.log(moment("2020-08-07 09:10:48").format())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Actually the year wrecked the time. Well, in date-fns it's lower y